# How can I completly uninstall eclipse elementary (ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, uninstallation

I've tried many times to delete eclipse by:

-sudo apt-get autoremove --purge eclipse

-rm -r .eclipse

and then it say that it's not installed, but if I try to install it again it say it's already been installed.

indeed if I do:

-whereis eclipse

eclipse: /usr/lib/eclipse /etc/eclipse.ini /snap/bin/eclipse

How can I totally uninstall and then install it again?

Comment: You seem to have it installed as a snap package, not through dpkg.

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to this location

> cd .local/share/applications/

Then remove all related files:

> rm *eclipse*.desktop epp*.desktop

Hope it will work for you

Comment: Warn: using * with ` markdown key make they in italic, so the command is different now. Can you edit your answer and use markdown ?

Comment: it say it's impossible rm: impossible remove 'eclipse.desktop': File o directory do not exist
rm: impossible remove 'epp*.desktop': File o directory do not exist

Comment: should I delete these directory? eclipse: /usr/lib/eclipse /etc/eclipse.ini /snap/bin/eclipse

Comment: in my home directory i can see eclipse and eclipse-installer